# call the method on slide of tab layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I my app there is activity dashboard activity, In that activity there is two bottom navigation menu, I have a problem in 1st menu name ALL order,

In the ALL order fragment class there is tab layout with viewpager2 adapter, and in each tab there is fragment...

In the fragment I have recyclerview and item of recyclerview come from api, and in recyclerview Item there is one button of accept order, on click of button the item should remove from recyclerview..

The code work fine till here, Now what i want is when the item remove from list immidiatly in another
tab fragment the recyclerview should update, so that my deleted item show at that 2nd tab..

which is handle by api call I just need to all the method again which I call when acitivity start, because the updated data not showing untill I come back in the activity again..

```
public class InProgress extends Fragment implements InProgressAdapter.OrderActionListener{

    ArrayList<InProgressOrderData> progressDataList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public InProgress() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_in_progress, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rvInProgress);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        progressDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        fetchData();
    }

    public void fetchData(){

        ApiService apiService = getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiService.class);

        Call<List<InProgressOrderData>> call = apiService.getPendingOrder();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<InProgressOrderData>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<InProgressOrderData>> call, Response<List<InProgressOrderData>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    progressDataList.addAll(response.body());
                    InProgressAdapter inProgressAdapter = new InProgressAdapter(getContext(),progressDataList, InProgress.this);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(inProgressAdapter);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<InProgressOrderData>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


    public void dispatchedOrder(String orderNo, int position){

        ApiService apiService = getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiService.class);

        UpdateOrderStatusData updateOrderStatusData = new UpdateOrderStatusData(orderNo,5);

        Call<UpdateOrderStatusData> call = apiService.updateOrderStatus(updateOrderStatusData);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<UpdateOrderStatusData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UpdateOrderStatusData> call, Response<UpdateOrderStatusData> response) {

                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    progressDataList.remove(position);
                    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Order Dispatched successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error In dispatching Order", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UpdateOrderStatusData> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed to Dispatched the  order", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public void onDispatchedOrder(String orderNo, int position) {
        dispatchedOrder(orderNo,position);
    }
}
```

## Where and how I call the fetchData() method again to show my updated data.. in recyclerview

## Below is My ViewPager2 Adapter Class and Main Fragment class where I implement the tab layout

## Class where I implement Tab Layout

```
public class AllOrderFragment extends Fragment {

    public AllOrderFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    View view;
    TabLayout tab;
    ViewPager2 viewPager2;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_order,container,false);

        myToolbar();

        tab = view.findViewById(R.id.tab);
        viewPager2 = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager2);

        viewPager2.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity()));

        TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(tab, viewPager2, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0:{
                        tab.setText("NewOrder");
                        break;
                    }
                    case 1:{
                        tab.setText("InProgress");
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2:{
                        tab.setText("Dispatched");
                        break;
                    }
                    case 3:{
                        tab.setText("Completed");
                        break;
                    }
                    case 4:{
                        tab.setText("Cancelled");
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        });
        tabLayoutMediator.attach();

        

        return view;
    }

    public void myToolbar(){
        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbarOrder);
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.setTitle("Orders");
                toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

            }
        }

    }
}
```

## ViewPagerAdapter Class

```
package com.RnDTechnosoft.pizzapizzeria.Adapter;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;

import com.RnDTechnosoft.pizzapizzeria.fragment.Cancelled;
import com.RnDTechnosoft.pizzapizzeria.fragment.Completed;
import com.RnDTechnosoft.pizzapizzeria.fragment.Dispatched;
import com.RnDTechnosoft.pizzapizzeria.fragment.InProgress;
import com.RnDTechnosoft.pizzapizzeria.fragment.NewOrder;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        super(fragmentActivity);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {

        if(position == 0){
            return new NewOrder();
        }
        else if(position == 1) {
            return new InProgress();
        }
        else if(position == 2){
            return new Dispatched();
        }
        else if(position == 3){
            return new Completed();
        }
        else { //cancelled
            return new Cancelled();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about after you update the order status ? I guess you can place your fetch method there and dont forget to put progressDataList.clear() in the first line of fetch method other wise duplicate items will get added.

Comment: Yes you are right , I do not clear the list first, Now I just add a swipeLayout there and in onSwipe clear the list and fetch the data again